# django email not sending ( using form )

Tags: django, django-email

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import Contact 
from django.core.mail import send_mail
def contact(response):
    if response.method=="POST":
        form= Contact(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            subject= "COMMENTS"
            send_mail(subject,comment,email,['nafiyadargaw360@gmail.com'],fail_silently=True)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/contact")
    else:
        form=Contact()
    context = {'form': form}
    template = 'contact/index.html'
    return render(response,template,context)
```

i get no error when i fill in the form but first the page doesnt redirect to /contact as told but when i try that using shell it works

Comment: are you sure that the `form.is_valid()` is returning ***`True`*** ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes there is no error

Comment: set `fail_silently=False` and try. Probably you will get some errors

Comment: @ArakkalAbu still no errors